# React Native: What exactly happens on hot reload / fast refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reload, hot-reload, metro-bundler

I am running a React Native app in an iOS emulator, and have fast refresh turned on. It seems like when a fast refresh occurs, the constructor for the component is run, but `componentDidMount` is not.

**What I Want To Know: ** What exactly happens on a fast refresh? What are the steps that are executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my experience, it will update the item what you change, if you don't change the code in `componentDidMount`, it will not change the render result caused by `componentDidMount` either, vice versa.

There are detail introductions in react native document.

[Hot reload](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading)

[Fast Refresh](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/09/18/version-0.61)